# Scala REPL fails to autocomplete methods that comes from implicit conversion

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

if I write in scala 2.10 REPL (interactive Scala shell):

```
 """\w""".
```

And press `TAB` it gives me:

```
+                     asInstanceOf          charAt                   
codePointAt           codePointBefore        
codePointCount        compareTo             compareToIgnoreCase       
concat                contains              ....
```

However, `.r` is missing. When I put the same string into eclipse, it offers me `.r` as well. The same is true if I insert `import scala.util.matching._` before.
Why REPL is not offering all possibilities?

Even bigger problem REPL has if i try to work with unicode, e.g. I write:

```
"""\p{L}""".
```

and press `TAB`
it gives me error:

```
scala> """\p{L}""".<console>:1: error: unclosed multi-line string literal
"""
^
```

Again, it works fine in Eclipse.

Is REPL so buggy, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REPL only displays fields and methods of the object, while `.r` is only available through an implicit conversion (`augmentString` in [`scala.Predef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef)) which turns it into a `StringOps`. There is probably no reason for this besides the fact that it would need to be implemented and nobody got around to doing it. You can still call `.r` on this, of course.

The Scala IDE is smart enough to [resolve implicits](http://scala-ide.org/docs/helium/features/implicit-highlighting/index.html), which is why you can see it there.

Comment: the link is out-of-date

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `r` is missing, but if you write `"""\w""".r` and press enter it nevertheless works `res0: scala.util.matching.Regex = \w`. Having tab autocompletion for `r` seems not really neccessary. 
The unicode issue is probably caused by java. You can explicitly request UTF-8 if you   pass `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to java. Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding/623036#623036) which describes how to do it.

If you use Eclipse, I can reccommend the [Scala worksheet plugin](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started) which is a very good repl replacement.

Comment: thanks, i agree with the exception of: "Having tab autocompletion for r seems not really neccessary." - it is necessary when you are looking for possibilities (if you are not sure which function to use)