# Why doesn't the Scala REPL list all possibilities when using TAB-completion?

Tags: scala

I have just started programming in Scala, and I noticed that  hitting TAB-completion in the Scala REPL doesn't show all the available methods.

E.g. I want to evaluate this expression -

```
"Hello".intersect("World")
```

So, I type

```
"Hello".inter
```

and press TAB and expect 'intersect' to be shown as a valid option, but it is not shown.

Why is this so? I am sure that it is not a bug. I don't have any other examples yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Intersect` is not a `String` method but instead implicitly inferred from `ArrayOps`, and the REPL's auto-complete doesn't cover implicits yet. So it's not exactly a bug, just a (desperately) missing feature.

There's no technical barrier for this. It's just that no one had time to implement it yet.

Sources:
[Scala REPL fails to autocomplete methods that comes from implicit conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267235/scala-repl-fails-to-autocomplete-methods-that-comes-from-implicit-conversion)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/B34-TqH8pGU

Comment: It's pretty desperate. Thanks for the ML link, I like the idea of expanding implicits on multiple tabs.